# Need advice on 2d arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I am currently working on a dungeon crawl game where the user can move throughout a maze on the screen. I decided to use a 2d array for the maze. One problem, I have a function to print the maze although its not working. I want it to print all four of the rows (there are supposed to be 4 0's per row) but it only prints 4 0's in a single line.

```
int maze[4][4] = {(0,0,0,0),
                  (0,0,0,0),
                  (0,0,0,0),
                  (0,0,0,0)};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

cout <<maze[i][i];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested loop for displaying 2D array. 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        cout<

Answer (score 2):

You need two loops, one nested inside the other.

One to print the rows.

One to print each column in the current row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        cout <<maze[i][j];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```